# What is meant by "the coefficients of a polynomial function $f(x)$ are symmetric functions of its roots"?

Tags: group-theory, polynomials

I am reading [Rotman's Introduction to Group Theory](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4176-8).

One of his first remarks is that:

> By the middle of the eighteenth
>   century, it was realized that permutations of the roots of a polynomial $f(x)$
>   were important; for example, it was known that the coefficients of $f(x)$ are
>   "symmetric functions" of its roots.

Aren't the coefficients of a polynomial function constants? How can they then be functions, let alone "symmetric functions"?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas) ?

Comment: @Lucian No, I wasn't before you pointed me to them - aha!

Comment: [Related](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial). Basically, there are "elementary symmetric polynomials" — in two variables they're $a+b$ and $ab$ — where every symmetric function can be written in terms of those. For example, $(a-b)^2$ is a symmetric polynomial, so it can be written in terms of $a+b$ and $ab$; sure enough, it's equal to $(a+b)^2-4(ab)$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinbergercolumbus Very interesting!

Comment: That particular example is actually important. Let's say we know $a+b$ and $ab$, and we want to find out $a$ and $b$. Well, we know that $a-b=\sqrt{(a+b)^2-4(ab)}$ (or its negative). Also, if we know $a-b$, we can figure out $a$ and $b$, since they're equal to $\frac{(a+b)\pm(a-b)}2$. Thus, we have that $a$ and $b$ are equal to:$$\frac{(a+b)\pm\sqrt{(a+b)^2-4(ab)}}2$$Combining this with Viete's formulae, it turns out that we've basically just rediscovered the quadratic formula; I'll leave it to you to fill in the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But that's the ingenuity that revolutionized the theory of solving polynomial equations - it's sort of the *reverse* of the usual situation! Normally we're given an actual polynomial and want to find its roots.

However, that doesn't stop us from deciding that we want certain roots and asking, "What kind of polynomial can I write down *with* these roots?" (By the way, questions like this arise quite naturally when you're writing quizzes and tests for students of the kind of algebra you learned years ago!)

Let's say we want a quadratic with roots $x = r_1$ and $x = r_2$. In this case, any quadratic of the form

$$p(x) = a(x - r_1)(x - r_2) = ax^2 -a(r_1 + r_2)x + ar_1r_2$$

has the roots we want, $r_1$ and $r_2$. So our coefficients for $x^2,\, x,$ and $1$ are respectively

- $a$ (which is completely independent of both $r_1$ and $r_2$; we could swap them, and it wouldn't change $a$)
- $-a(r_1 + r_2)$ which again remains invariant under permuting the two roots, and
- $ar_1r_2$, another function of $r_1$ and $r_2$ that doesn't depend on which is which.

This is an example of the sort of thing they mean.

Comment: I accepted your answer (while upvoting every other answer, since they all added something interesting/generalized your answer), because it helped me understand the other answers clearly. Thank you!

Comment: @user89 Sure thing! Having a couple of viewpoints definitely helps.

Comment: Shouldn't the bullet points be $a$, $-a(r_1+r_2)$, and $ar_1r_2$? Since they're supposed to be the coefficients of $x^2$, $x$, and $1$.

Comment: Indeed they should be, @Akiva, good catch - I remember thinking that, but apparently forgetting just as quickly!

Answer (score 6):

Consider the cubic of the form $x^3+Px^2+Qx+R$, and suppose it has roots $a$, $b$, and $c$. Then:
\begin{align}
P&=-a-b-c\\
Q&=ab+ac+bc\\
R&=-abc
\end{align}
These are called "symmetric" functions of $a$, $b$, and $c$, because switching them around doesn't change the value of the function.

Proof: This follows from noting that the cubic is $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$. Just multiply it out and equate coefficients.

Answer (score 5):

If you know what the roots of a polynomial are, you can use those roots to compute the coefficients, up to a constant factor. This means that, for example for monic fifth-degree polynomials, there is a function that takes the five roots as inputs and produces, say, the coefficient of $x^2$ in the polynomial. (To emphasize, this is *one* function that works for *all* degree-5 polynomials).

It is this function that is *symmetric*, meaning that the coefficient it produces does not depend on which order you feed the various roots to it. (Moreover the coefficient-generating functions are themselves polynomials in several variables).

Comment: At first, I was going to question what you meant by "[result of a function] does not depend on which order you feed the various roots to it"...since so far, I always thought the order of the variables in function notation was not important (i.e. I thought that $f(x, y) = f(y, x)$, for all functions), but then upon further thought I realized once we fix which variable corresponds to which "slot" in the function notation, then the ordering of the variables in the slots does matter. Thanks for that insight.

Answer (score 2):

Let's introduce a bit of notation first: let $f(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 x + a_0$ where each $a_i \in \mathbb{C}$ (if the coefficient of $x^n$ is not $1$, factor it out of the polynomial).  Then the fundamental theorem of algebra tells us that $f$ has $n$ (not necessarily distinct roots) $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n$.  Then we can also write $f(x) = (x - \omega_1)(x - \omega_2)\cdots (x - \omega_n)$.  If we multiply this all out and equate coefficients, we can express each $a_i$ in terms of the roots; in this sense, the $a_i$'s are functions of the roots, and we can write $a_i(\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n)$.  If you were to multiply it out, this $a_i$ is going to be a polynomial in $n$ variables

Now, given a function of $n$ variables, $g(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, we say that $g$ is a symmetric function iff $g(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = g(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)})$ for every $\sigma \in S_n$.  That is, $g$ is a symmetric function if we can permute the variables without changing the function.  We then see that the $a_i$'s can be viewed as symmetric functions of the roots in that we can permute the order of the roots without changing the coefficients. That is, the function $a_i(\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n)$ is a symmetric polynomial in $n$  variables.

Comment: I just learned what $S_n$ is, and your answer might have confused me if I hadn't learned of it. I tried to submit an edit to clarify what you meant by $S_n$.

Comment: Okay.  Elements of $S_n$ permute the numbers $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$; in the context of my answer, $\sigma$ is permuting the indices of the $x_i$, not the variables themselves, which has the same effect as switching the variables around.

Comment: Ah! I see. Okay, yeah, my edit would have been incorrect then. Thank you for clarifying and teaching me some new notation.

Comment: Rotman provides the definition of $S_X$ as: If $X$ is a nonempty set, a permutation of $X$ is a bijection $\alpha: X \mapsto X$. We denote the set of all permutations of $X$ by $S_X$. In general, it doesn't matter what the elements of $X$ are, correct? It is only $S_n$ that specifies further that we are dealing with the set of $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly correct.  $S_n$ is typically used as a permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, and $S_X$ consists of bijections on $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a quadratic polynomial with roots $r_1$ and $r_2$. If you expand $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)=x^2-(r_1+r_2)x+r_1r_2$ you can see that the coefficients of this quadratic are related to its roots in a way that’s independent of the order in which you list the roots. Similarly, for a cubic, its coefficients are $-(r_1+r_2+r_3)$, $(r_1r_2+r_1r_3+r_2r_3)$ and $-(r_1r_2r_3)$. These values, too, are clearly independent of the order in which you list the three roots. This sort of symmetry holds for higher-degree polynomials as well.